# Better way to write this query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Whenever I update a field, there may be some data that needs to be distributed to other documents within a collection. I currently have this:

```js
Model.find({
    _id: {
        $in: ids
    }
}).stream().on('data', (doc) => {
    doc['relatedData'] = relatedData; //Just to demonstrate
    doc['arrayOfData'] = otherRelatedData[doc['_id']];

    doc.save((err) => if (error) throw new Error(error));
});
```

It is currently written with Mongoose, but the MongoDB equivalent would be this:

```js
db.collection.find(...).forEach(...);
```

Is  there any way to write this query with a single update query?

Comment: No, as the updates are different for each one.  If you were setting them all to the same data then yes.

Comment: Depending on how much data you have (whether your application can hold it in memory) you could bulk update though.  I'm not sure that it would be faster, but maybe it's something to consider.

Comment: @BanksySan It really depends on the data which is in the key value pairs. This part `otherRelatedData[doc['_id']]`.

Comment: Aye, that's what I mean.  If that statement isn't a constant then you can't update them all in one go.